# change maximum number of open files for user on solaris 9

Tags: solaris, ulimit

i need to change ulimit -n for the user permanently, on solaris 10 you can do 
`projadd -K "process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,8192,deny)" proj.files`
but on solaris 9 `projadd` or `projmod` doesn't have `-K` key. Adding
`proj.files:100::::process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,8192,deny)` to /etc/project doesn't help either.